# RTVS plotting disconnects R session

Tags: r, rtvs

When I try to make a simple plot in R using RTVS like `plot(1:100)` that states "Interactive Window is disconnected from R session.  Click "Reset" to start a new session."

The Plotting device shows "R Plot - Device 0", and I can't get a value other than 0 for the plot device.  I've tried to use the dev.* functions, but usually the same behavior results.  The workaround I've found is to use windows() to start a new R plotting window, but this is far from desired.

I've even gone as far as completely resetting my laptop (it's relatively new, so wasn't too much of a pain to reset).